# How to json_encode utf8?

Tags: php

```
$obj = [{"name":"Hình Ảnh","url":"images"}];
$str = json_encode($obj);
```

result:

```
[{"name":"H\u00ecnh \u1ea2nh","url":"hinh_anh"}]
```

Why?

Why `$str` not is:

```
[{"name":"Hình Ảnh","url":"images"}];
```

Comment: Because that's how it is. See JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE for the non-standard encoding.

Comment: decode it back and it's the same again

Comment: of course decode it back but in need save string to json file with file_put_contents.

Answer (score 2):

Add your file this code

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;
```

and change

```
$str = json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: I see, I was do it, but this result with: json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
==> json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in
note: